# Error by Mounting shared volumes on windows

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

on a Windows os `$ winpty docker run -it -v c: / data: / data alpine ls data` sets windows ;C to the volume and outputs the following error message.
The command is executed in the git bash
How do I fix this problem?

```
$ winpty docker run -it -v c:/data:/data alpine ls data
C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Mount denied:
The source path "c;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\data;C"
is not a valid Windows path.
See 'C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe run --help'.
```

Comment: can you try wrapping mount options under "" like docker run -it -v "c:/data:/data" alpine ls /data

Comment: then I get the same error message :/
even if I docker run --rm -v c:/Users./data alpine ls /data Input as described in the settings under the rider shared drives I get the error